# Java - String Array Conversion to Long Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, long-integer

Still new to java and new to arrays. I'm having difficulty reading data from a CSV into a String array and converting it to an long array that can handle only the numbers. I'm doing this so that I can eventually try and find maximum / minimum values, averages, etc. In the second image below, you can see I printed my data to the screen from the String array. My CSV has 20 columns and 21 rows. When I tried to parse and convert, my array printed partial data and filled most of the indexes with 0's. I am trying to figure out if converted it wrong or if its an issues with the for loop I have which sifts through the array indexes.

```html
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.Math;


public class USCrimes {
  int year;
  long population;
  long violentCrime;
  double violentCrimeRate;
  long murderManslaughter;
  double murderManslaughterRate;
  long rape;
  double rapeRate;
  long robbery;
  double robberyRate;
  long aggravatedAssault;
  double aggravatedAssaultRate;
  long propertyCrime;
  double propertyCrimeRate;
  long burglary;
  double burglaryRate;
  long larcenyTheft;
  double larcenyTheftRate;
  long motorVehicleTheft;
  double motorVehicleTheftRate;
  String fileName= "C:/Users/micha/OneDrive/Documents/College/SEP 18/Crime.csv";
  String crimeArray[];

    //getter and setter methods for variables between lines 17 - 36
    public void setYear(int year) {
      this.year = year;
    }

    public int getYear() {
      return year;
    }

    public long getViolentCrime() {
      return violentCrime;
    }

    public void setViolentCrime(long violentCrime) {
      this.violentCrime = violentCrime;
    }

    public double getViolentCrimeRate() {
      return violentCrimeRate;
    }

    public void setViolentCrimeRate(double violentCrimeRate) {
      this.violentCrimeRate = violentCrimeRate;
    }

    public long getMurderManslaughter() {
      return murderManslaughter;
    }

    public void setMurderManslaughter(long murderManslaughter) {
      this.murderManslaughter = murderManslaughter;
    }

    public double getMurderManslaughterRate() {
      return murderManslaughterRate;
    }

    public void setMurderRate(double murderManslaughterRate) {
      this.murderManslaughterRate = murderManslaughterRate;
    }

    public long getRape() {
      return rape;
    }

    public void setRape(Long rape) {
      this.rape = rape;
    }

    public double getRapeRate() {
      return rapeRate;
    }

    public void setRapeRate(double rapeRate) {
      this.rapeRate = rapeRate;
    }

    public long getRobbery() {
      return robbery;
    }

    public void setRobbery(long robbery) {
      this.robbery = robbery;
    }

    public double getRobberyRate() {
      return robberyRate;
    }

    public void setRobberyRate(float robberyRate) {
      this.robberyRate = robberyRate;
    }

    public long getAggravatedAssault() {
      return aggravatedAssault;
    }

    public void setAggravatedAssault(long aggravatedAssault) {
      this.aggravatedAssault = aggravatedAssault;
    }

    public double getAggravatedAssaultRate() {
      return aggravatedAssaultRate;
    }

    public void setAggravatedAssaultRate(double aggravatedAssaultRate) {
      this.aggravatedAssaultRate = aggravatedAssaultRate;
    }

    public long getPropertyCrime() {
      return propertyCrime;
    }

    public void setPropertyCrime(long propertyCrime) {
      this.propertyCrime = propertyCrime;
    }

    public double getPropertyCrimeRate() {
      return propertyCrimeRate;
    }

    public void setPropertyCrime(double propertyCrimeRate) {
      this.propertyCrimeRate = propertyCrimeRate;
    }

    public long getBurglary() {
      return burglary;
    }

    public void setBurglary(long burglary) {
      this.burglary = burglary;
    }

    public double getBurglaryRate() {
      return burglaryRate;
    }

    public void setBurglaryRate(double burglaryRate) {
      this.burglaryRate = burglaryRate;
    }

    public long getLarcernyTheft() {
      return larcenyTheft;
    }

    public void setLarcenyTheft(long larcenyTheft) {
      this.larcenyTheft = larcenyTheft;
    }

    public double getLarcernyTheftRate() {
      return larcenyTheftRate;
    }

    public void setLarcenyTheftRate(double larcenyTheftRate) {
      this.larcenyTheftRate = larcenyTheftRate;
    }

    public long getMotorVehicleTheft() {
      return motorVehicleTheft;
    }

    public void setMotorVehicleTheft(long motorVehicleTheft) {
      this.motorVehicleTheft = motorVehicleTheft;
    }

    public double getMotorVehicleTheftRate() {
      return motorVehicleTheftRate;
    }

    public void setMotorVehicleTheftRate(double motorVehicleTheftRate) {
      this.motorVehicleTheftRate = motorVehicleTheftRate;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
      return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
      this.fileName = fileName;
    //end getter and setter methods for variables between lines 17 - 36

    }
}

  class TestUSCrime{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          USCrimes newUSCrimes = new USCrimes();
          long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          BufferedReader br = null;
          String csvComma = ",";
          String line = "";
          int index = 0;

          System.out.println("********** Welcome to the USCrime Statistical Application **************************\n");
          System.out.println("Which US Crime file would you like to use?\n");


          String userInput = input.nextLine();
          input.close();

          //printing the menu for user selection
          System.out.println("Please enter the number for the question you would like answered. At any time, enter Q to quit the program:\n");
          System.out.println("1. What were the percentages in population growth for each consecutive year from 1994 ñ 2013?");
          System.out.println("2. What year was the Murder rate the highest?");
          System.out.println("3. What year was the Murder rate the lowest?");
          System.out.println("4. What year was the Robbery rate the highest?");
          System.out.println("5. What year was the Robbery rate the lowest?");
          System.out.println("6. What was the total percentage change in MotorVehicle Theft between 1998 and 2012?");
          System.out.println("7. What year was the Violent Crime rate the highest?");
          System.out.println("8. What year was the Violent Crime rate the ");
          System.out.println("");
          //setting the filename for user defined input
          newUSCrimes.setFileName(userInput);

          try {
              br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newUSCrimes.fileName));
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  String [] crimesArray = line.split(csvComma);
                  long[] crimesArrayNumbers = new long[crimesArray.length];


                  System.out.println(crimesArray[0] + " , "+ crimesArray[1] + " , " + crimesArray[2] + " , " + crimesArray[3]);

                   for(int i = 0; i < crimesArrayNumbers.length;i++)
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           crimesArrayNumbers[index] = Long.parseLong(crimesArray[i]);
                           index++;}

                      catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioob){
                        }
                      catch (NumberFormatException e){
                      }
                  }//end for loop
                        crimesArrayNumbers = Arrays.copyOf(crimesArrayNumbers, index);
                        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(crimesArrayNumbers));
            }//end try

              System.out.println();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
              try {
                  br.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
            }

          System.out.println("Thank you for trying the US Crimes Statistics Program.");

          //calculating the elapsed time using milliseconds and subsequently dividing by 1000.
          long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();;
          long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
          System.out.println("Elapsed time in seconds was: " + (timeElapsed / 1000));

          if (args.length != 1) {
              System.out.println("Usage: \"java TestUSCrime Crime.csv");
            return;
        } // end if
    } //end main
} //end TestUSCrimes
```

[image: Output for the long[] crimeArrayNumbers. Most of my values are 0]
[image: Output for String [] crimeArray from the CSV data]

Comment: Time to use a debugger to isolate and identify your bug. One small issue is that you appear to be misusing inheritance as the TestUSCrime should definitely *not* inherit from USCrime class. Also the USCrime class should not have any user interface within it at all (no println's and no scanner).

Comment: I have made the recommended changes that you had to my code. No more extends and I cut out the showMenu() method.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to isolate your error yet? This is something that only you can (and should) do, and best to do before coming here.

Comment: I did use a debugger and it would not have caught my error as Selindek indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reset the index variable inside the main loop. Add

```
index=0;
```

before this line

```
for(int i = 0; i < crimesArrayNumbers.length;i++)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issues. Could you explain it a bit further on why this solution worked? I need to put it to memory.

Comment: You didn't reset the index, so when you read the 2nd line the code starts populate the 2nd array at that index. In your example it found 12 numbers in the first line, so it started to add the numbers form the 13th position in the next line... and from 25 in the 3rd, which is actually doesn't even exist.